# Curl under proxy for django restframework giving value: Unable to parse connection string: ""

Tags: python, django, curl, proxy, django-rest-framework

When i use curl under proxy for rest framework api testing in django i'm getting this error `Exception Value: Unable to parse connection string: ""`

i have used

`curl -v --noproxy localhost -X POST -H "Authorization: Token <token id >" -d "email=d@c.co" "http://localhost:4000/api/....."`

and also tried

`export http_proxy=""`

while was working properly when i was not under proxy

`curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Token <token id >" -d "email=d@c.co" "http://localhost:4000/api/....."`

Answer (score 0):

From the manual of `--noproxy`, it expects -

> Comma-separated list of hosts which do not use a proxy, if one is  specified.  The only wildcard is a single * character, which matches all hosts, and effectively  disables  the  proxy.

So you must specify a comma separated list of hosts. That may be either specific hosts such as `"localhost:4000"` or `"*"`.

So the following should work-

```
curl -v --noproxy "*" localhost -X POST -H "Authorization: Token <token id >" -d "email=d@c.co" "http://localhost:4000/api/....."
```